# How can I solve this Uncaught TypeError: $elements.tooltip is not a function?

Tags: 8, javascript, bootstrap-theme

### Problem

The tooltips don't work. I have the following error message in Chrome's JS console.

> jquery.min.js?v=3.2.1:2 
>   Uncaught TypeError: $elements.tooltip is not a function
>       at Object.removeAllTooltips (Tooltip.js:71)
>       at Object.init (Tooltip.js:59)
>       at ein_tooltip_init (Tooltip.js:75)
>       at HTMLDocument. (Tooltip.js:84)
>       at j (jquery.min.js?v=3.2.1:2)
>       at k (jquery.min.js?v=3.2.1:2)

### My Environment

I've got the following setup:

- Drupal 8.7.4
- Drush 8.1.17
- base theme: Radix 8.x-4.3
- custom sub-theme
- Node.js v11.7.0
- yarn 1.13.0

### Theme setup

I have the following theme definition in **MYTHEME.info.yml**:

```
name: MYTHEME
description: A custom theme for MYTHEME based on Radix.
screenshot: screenshot.png
# core: 8.x
# version: VERSION
engine: twig
type: theme
base theme: radix

regions:
  …

libraries:
  - radix/style
  - MYTHEME/style
  - MYTHEME/tooltip

libraries-override:
  radix/bootstrap: false

ckeditor_stylesheets:
  - assets/css/MYTHEME.style.css

component-libraries:
  ein:
    paths:
      - ./src/components

entity_print:
 node:
   # Adds ein-legislation css library to the Legislation bundle on the Node entity.
    …

# Information added by Drupal.org packaging script on 2018-10-03
version: '8.x-4.0'
core: '8.x'
project: 'radix'
datestamp: 1538551089
```

The libraries as defined in **MYTHEME.libraries.yml**:

```
style:
  …

tooltip:
  js:
    assets/js/Tooltip.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
    - core/drupal

sidebar-collapse:
  …

legislation-printable:
  …

other-printable:
  …
```

I can see in the sources tabs that the **bootstrap.bundle.js** is being included in the webpack, the jQuery is loading fine.
The actual JS responsible for invoking the Bootstrap 4 tooltips - **Tooltip.js**:

```js
'use strict';
//import $ from 'jquery';
// import 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle';

(function ($) {

  let tooltip_initialized = false;

  function ein_tooltip_init (context) {
    if ( !tooltip_initialized ) {

      console.log(`jQ in tooltip/Tooltip.js`);
      console.dir($);
      // $.noConflict(true);
      if (typeof Object.assign != 'function') {
        Object.assign = function(target, varArgs) {
          'use strict';
          if (target == null) { // TypeError if undefined or null
            throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
          }

          var to = Object(target);
          for (var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
            var nextSource = arguments[index];

            if (nextSource != null) { // Skip over if undefined or null
              for (var nextKey in nextSource) {
                // Avoid bugs when hasOwnProperty is shadowed
                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(nextSource, nextKey)) {
                  to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
                }
              }
            }
          }
          return to;
        };
      }

      const Tooltip = {
        Options: {
          delay: {
            show: 1000,
            hide: 300
          },
          placement: 'left',
          trigger: 'hover',
        },
        init() {
          // Tooltip options for buttons in the bundlemaker
          Tooltip.OptionsBundlemaker = Object.assign({}, Tooltip.Options, { placement: 'bottom' });

          const $anchorsAll = Tooltip.getAllTooltipAnchors();
          const $anchorsBundlemaker = $anchorsAll.filter((index, elem) => elem.parentNode.className === `mybundles-header` );
          const $anchorsOther = $anchorsAll.filter( (index, elem) => elem.parentNode.className != `mybundles-header` );

          Tooltip.removeAllTooltips($anchorsAll);
          $anchorsOther.tooltip(Tooltip.Options);
          $anchorsBundlemaker.tooltip(Tooltip.OptionsBundlemaker);
          console.info(`Tooltip init ✔︎`);
          tooltip_initialized = true;
        },
        getAllTooltipAnchors() {
          return $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]');
        },
        removeAllTooltips($elements) {
          // Kill all tooltips
          $('.tooltip').remove(); // remove any active tooltips
          $elements.tooltip('dispose'); // hide and destroy any existing tooltips
        }
      };

      Tooltip.init();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  Drupal.behaviors.einTooltip = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        ein_tooltip_init(context);
      });
    }
  }
})(jQuery, Drupal);
//export default Tooltip
```

My package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "MYTHEME",
  "description": "A theme based on Radix.",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "find node_modules/ -name '*.info' -type f -delete",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "hot": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "production": "NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^4.1.4",
    "laravel-mix-bundle-analyzer": "^1.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.5",
    "rupture-sass": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "not ie 10",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Where is `.tooltip()` supposed to come from? From the `bootstrap.bundle` you are importing in your `Tooltip.js` (better use lower case file names)? Better add it as separate library and then set it as dependency of yours.

Comment: `.tooltip()` comes from the `bootstrap.bundle` together with `popper.js`. I have tried to import these as separate libraries but it didn't work either.

Comment: Don’t forget Drupal doesn’t (and cant) affect anything once the page is loaded and you’re client side. So if `jQuery.tooltip` doesn’t exist, it’s because it’s not in any of the JS files loaded into the page, or it _is_ and some other code has deleted it before your code runs. Maybe it’s literally missing from the bundle file? Maybe the bundle file isn’t loaded properly? Maybe you’ve got a version of the bundle file which isn’t integrated with jQuery? Approach your debugging as if it was a static HTML site and you should find it easier

Comment: So, I've found _a solution_ thanks to this [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48549940/1337386): I have to `import 'jquery';` before loading the bootstrap dependency within the Tooltip.js file. Otherwise the `.tooltip()` does not get registered as jQuery plugin. This however means, I'm loading jQuery multiple times – with Drupal and bundled in with the Tooltip.js file. Not ideal. How should I go about this _the Drupal way_?